# How to grab text from each xml tag when the tags have multiple duplications

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, for-loop

Sorry if the question is obscure but this example xml tells it completely.

```
<Components>
    <Component>
        <ComponentID>B1</ComponentID>
        <ComponentName>replace</ComponentName>
        <Description>replace</Description>
    </Component>
    <Component>
        <ComponentID>D2</ComponentID>
        <ComponentName>Red</ComponentName>
        <Description>Red</Description>
    </Component>
    <Component>
        <ComponentID>D3</ComponentID>
        <ComponentName>Yellow</ComponentName>
        <Description>Yellow</Description>
    </Component>
</Components>
```

Essentially I want to save each of these components to a dictionary. I have tried this code:

```
if elem1.tag == 'Components':
    for elem2 in list(elem1):
        if elem2.tag == 'Component':
            temp = 0
            for elem3 in list(elem2):
                if elem3.tag == 'ComponentID':
                    temp+=1
                    asset['CompID'+str(temp)] = elem3.text
            for elem3 in list(elem2):
                if elem3.tag == 'ComponentName':
                    temp+=1
                    asset['CompName'+str(temp)] = elem3.text
            for elem3 in list(elem2):
                if elem3.tag == 'Description':
                    temp+=1
                    asset['Description'+str(temp)] = elem3.text
```

But the issues that happen is that even though each dictionary key will be unique, it is still only the last found component that information will be obtained.

Current output:

```
{'CompID1': 'D3', 'CompName2': 'Yellow', 'Description3': 'Yellow'}
```

Desired output:

```
{'CompID1': 'B1', 'CompName1': 'replace', 'Description1': 'replace',
'CompID2': 'D2', 'CompName2': 'Red', 'Description2': 'Red',
'CompID3': 'D3', 'CompName3': 'Yellow', 'Description3': 'Yellow'}
```

I know my temp calls and allocation may be wrong, but it is the assigning of the text values within each tag that is the main problem as it only finds the last one. The final solution will need dictionaries at the end for use in other methods and functions. So while any tips and solutions are welcomed, if they can be focused on dictionaries that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change it:

```
if elem1.tag == 'Components':
    temp = 0
    for elem2 in list(elem1):
        if elem2.tag == 'Component':
            for elem3 in list(elem2):
                if elem3.tag == 'ComponentID':
                    asset['CompID'+str(temp)] = elem3.text
                if elem3.tag == 'ComponentName':
                    asset['CompName'+str(temp)] = elem3.text
                if elem3.tag == 'Description':
                    asset['Description'+str(temp)] = elem3.text
            temp+=1
```

Comment: Thank you that is perfect, if you have time would you mind explaining where I went wrong. Was it due to, too many for loops for each inner tag search? Then tied with the fact I incremented temp after each find? Or am I missing something more important?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips that might help you here:

- Use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to count the `<Component>` elements for you.
- Use a `keyname` dict to map between tags (e.g. `ComponentID`) and
  desired result keys (e.g. `CompID`)

---

For example, using [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/), with this setup:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import pprint

content = '''
<Components>
    <Component>
        <ComponentID>B1</ComponentID>
        <ComponentName>replace</ComponentName>
        <Description>replace</Description>
    </Component>
    <Component>
        <ComponentID>D2</ComponentID>
        <ComponentName>Red</ComponentName>
        <Description>Red</Description>
    </Component>
    <Component>
        <ComponentID>D3</ComponentID>
        <ComponentName>Yellow</ComponentName>
        <Description>Yellow</Description>
    </Component>
</Components>
'''
```

The code:

```
keyname = {'ComponentID' : 'CompID',
           'ComponentName': 'CompName'}
result = {}
doc = ET.fromstring(content)
for i, component in enumerate(doc.xpath('Component'), 1):
    for node in component:
        key = '{t}{i}'.format(t = keyname.get(node.tag, node.tag), i = i)
        result[key] = node.text
pprint.pprint(result)
```

yields

```
{'CompID1': 'B1',
 'CompID2': 'D2',
 'CompID3': 'D3',
 'CompName1': 'replace',
 'CompName2': 'Red',
 'CompName3': 'Yellow',
 'Description1': 'replace',
 'Description2': 'Red',
 'Description3': 'Yellow'}
```